# My application can't find a library class though it is in it

Tags: android

In [the android application I am writing](https://github.com/loloof64/ChessPositionManagerAndroid), I am using a [custom android project](https://github.com/loloof64/AndroidFileExplorer). Both compiles fine : particularly I could import the file_explorer_library-release aar in my application project.

But when launching the application in an emulator, I am getting an error saying that a library class could not be found, though when seeking for it in the integrated aar, I found the requested class (FileExplorerActivity) :

```
01-30 14:55:24.859    2132-2132/com.loloof64.android.chess_position_manager E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:     com.loloof64.android.file_explorer_library.FileExplorerActivity
            at com.loloof64.android.chess_position_manager.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:61)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

My main concern is that it is an error from my library coding or from my library management inside ChessPositionManager project, but which ?

Notice that both projects are built inside Android Studio (1.0) : what I did is placing the built FileExplorer aar into the libs folder of ChessPositionManager app module, and adapted the app module gradle script (changes are already reflected in the repository).

Comment: Is the jar checked in Java Build path->order and export?

Comment: Sorry : I forgot to mention that both projects are built inside Android Studio (1.0) In fact, I've just added the library aar to the app module libs folder of ChessPositionManager and adapted gradle script

Comment: Do you use ProGuard? Seems like ProGuard has removed that

Comment: Checking on the ChessPositionManager app module Gradle script : yes Proguard is used.

Comment: So the rule to keep the classes is missing, add a rule and check if that solves the problem

Comment: It appears to me that is strange : in previous version of ChessPositionManager and FileExplorerLibrary, the emulator could run the code. And I didn't change anything inside proguard configurations. Just either in Gradle scripts, or in projects code.